# Matrix ordering inside group with specific grouping first

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I'm having a problem with a report layout.

All these values are coming from the bank, no calculation is needed in SQL.

I have three columns, Ranking, Year and Company.

I have a row group for Company, and a column group for Year. I want to sort the results of the ranking, but I want the latest year to sort "first":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your group to have two sorting expressions.

The second will just be your current sorting expression, i.e. based on `Ranking`.

The first sorting expression will be something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!Year.Value = DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Today()), 0, 1)
```

This is checking your `Year` value against the current day's year - if they match, the expression assigns a value *0*, and all other rows will be assigned a value of *1*.

This means that the current year will always be first, but then all other years will be sorted by the second sorting expression, e.g. `Ranking` in your case.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work.

I solved it by ordering inside query.